# WYSIWYM editor for desktop (.NET/WinForms)

Tags: .net, text-editor, desktop-application, wysiwym

What can I use as WYSIWYM editor for desktop application (preferably .NET/WinForms)? I need functions as paragraphs, headings 1, 2, 3, (un)ordered lists, strong and no other formating (restrictive). Editor [wymeditor.org](http://www.wymeditor.org/) is bad for me purpose because I can paste anything to it from clipboard. I prefer no webbrowser/javascript editor integration. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xstandard](http://xstandard.com/en/documentation/xstandard-dev-guide/app-integration/vs-net/) works in both the web browser and in desktop apps (as an ActiveX control). I've used it excessively in web browsers since it produces clean markup, but I haven't tried it in WinForms myself.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express includes a Graphical Windows Forms editor that I would call WYSIWYM.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an HTML edit control, which matches all the requirements that you mentioned: see http://www.modeltext.com/html/ for details.